# Will the long-running task save the output?

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-ec2

I use amazon instance (linux) to compute C++ app like below:

```
screen ./app -params blablabla >> output
```

The task is running hours. I use `screen` because otherwise the result is not stored in output (checked twice), probably because of the ssh connection loss and consequent termination of the `app` process by linux policy (that is, `./app -params blablabla >> output` command is executing for 3 hours and then terminates without output).

Question: will screen help to get the output finally?

Comment: You may want to use `nohup yourcommand >> output &` instead.

Comment: Does your app generate output to stdout?

Comment: Yes, it prints statements like this `cout << timeDone << "Done." << endl;`.

Comment: Personally, I'd also redirect the output to `std::cout` to a file, e.g., using `std::ofstream out("some.log"); std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());` (there is a bit more to the redirection as the stream buffer needs to be reset). If the output should also go to standard output, I'd use `teebuf` writing both to standard output and a file. Of course, this is independent of the process being terminated, i.e., you'd still need to use `nohup`.

Comment: So with `screen` this will not work?